# How to avoid having constraint created by hibernate without having access to the entity

Tags: java, hibernate, unique-constraint, spring-boot-test, dbunit

I have an entity where I cant have access to modify a wrong `unique=true` into the column definition

```
@Embeddable
class SomePk{
    @Column(name="PERSON_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=15)
    public long getPersonId() {
        return this.personId;
    }
}
```

Using DB-Rider/DBUnit with Hibernate and Spring into JUnitTests the tables and constraints are auto-created before inserts are done according to DB-rider principles.

Am looking for a way of either avoid this constraint creation. Having something like `com.my.package.SomePk.PERSON_ID:forceUnique=false`

Looked into insert listeners, as well as [hibernate reverse engineering config](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e4485) but didnt find a way yet...

Comment: Like I answered on discourse, this is not possible. https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/avoid-having-constraint-created-by-hibernate-without-having-access-to-the-entity/6636/2

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is to copy-paste into JUnitTests the entity causing the issue with same package name, remove the uniqueness into this second class and the latter replaced the wrong one. I had this issue into a Springboot JUnitTest.